# Emailvalidation regex

Tags: .net, regex, validation, email, unicode

I am aware of the trouble with validating emails. Im not looking for the "wall of regex". I'm simply looking to fix the regex i already have.

```
^[\p{L}0-9!$'*+\-_]+(\.[\p{L}0-9!$'*+\-_]+)*@[\p{L}0-9]+(\.[\p{L}0-9]+)*(\.[\p{L}]{2,})$
```

This regex validates most emails, even unicode characters. I'm having trouble getting it working with domain names containing a dash.

Can you help me extend the domain validation part to include dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both instances of `[\p{L}0-9]+` after the `@` would have to have `-` added to the character group, eg `[\p{L}0-9-]+`. You might want to extend that to disallow leading and trailing hyphens, although the further you get into making your expression reflect reality the closer you will get to that wall of regex.

Note that neither IDNA (for the domain part) nor RFC 6531 (for the local part) limit Unicode characters to the Letter class.